# What are the steps to create and use custom themes in OpenUI5 without SAP license?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am looking for steps (end to end) on how to create and use custom theme in custom OpenUI5 apps.

I have looked at the OpenUI5 code in GitHub and it is still a bit not clear for me as far as the end to end process goes.

Here's what I have understood so far

1. Each control has its own `*.less` file for each theme and there is `base.less` with the color definitions.
2. A grunt task loops through the LESS files and  generates one common `library.css` for each library (`sap.ui.core`, `sap.m`, etc..)
3. Add the CSS in the `resources` folder as shown [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/09/19/create-and-apply-custom-theme-to-sapui5-application)

Is this correct, or am I missing a way to create custom themes **without any SAP software license?**

I think the "UI Theme Designer" needs SAP software to be installed. I am looking for something not linked with the SAP environment.

Comment: There is an [upcoming tool](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents/issues#issuecomment-885540484) to create custom themes. Once UI5 fully migrates to CSS variables, I guess we can make use of the new tool. Or maybe it's already possible with `data-sap-ui-xx-cssvariables="true"`? Haven't tried it yet.