# How to consume OpenUI5 custom themes in the same project?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I have started exploring my OpenUI5 app from this template - [openui5-basic-template-app](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-basic-template-app).

I need to create custom theme for my OpenUI5 WebApp.
I have gone through this sample - https://github.com/matz3/ui5con17-custom-theme

I have already gone through following links - [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/09/19/create-and-apply-custom-theme-to-sapui5-application/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450341/what-are-the-steps-to-create-and-use-a-custom-theme-in-openui5-without-theme-bu)

**Now question is, How can I combine these two projects together so that I can use ui5con17-custom-theme in my** [openui5-basic-template-app](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-basic-template-app)

How to use custom theme, or how to refer custom theme in UI5 webApp???

I am very new in OpenUI5 app development. Please help!!!

Comment: All my app files are under root > webapp folder. Can I add theme files in root > src folder ? If yes, How can I build the theme project along with webapp.... and consume the themes in root > webapp > index.html

Answer (score -1):

If your main question is how to point your app to the custom theme, then have a look at the second half of the ["Setting Themes" page in the SDK](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e9fc648661d84ed89360bbec3ae02611)

E.g. set the theme-roots bootstrap attribute to tell UI5 where to load the theme from:

```
data-sap-ui-theme-roots='{"my_theme" : "<URL_of_root_folder_of_custom_theme>"}'
```

Below this root, UI5 will automatically create sup-paths according to the used control libraries.

Of course also set the "data-sap-ui-theme" attribute to the name of your theme the same way you would normally select one of the default themes.

If something fails, check in the network trace from where the browser attempts to load the theme files.